# How to Add the ''EditText:searching field'' to my Java and make it Interactive?

Tags: android-edittext, search-box, audacity

I started learning about making apps in Android Studio few days ago , and my goal is to build an app that Shows a list of book with certain details by fetching Data from the GoogleBook Api  , i want to know how to display the result on the screen after typing in the " editText : searching field ?? i Really need your help , Thanks in Advance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6sTh.jpg)

Comment: I think you need to calm down and learn first. Learn about APIs and then populating views with data from APIs... This **IS NOT** basic stuff.